# How does God reconstruct your brain if it has been destroyed in the afterlife

Tags: afterlife

*(Disclaimer: Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker, feel free to correct my english if it is poor)*

In which state your brain is restored after death ? Does the bible said something about that ?

I have long been asked that question to myself, what memories do you brings with you when you die ? What God choose to bring back if your brain were destroyed in, for example, a car accident ? You know, it is common to read some news about people that loose their ability to pronounce some kind of word our doing something in particular, it is restored ?

Worst to answer, If someone suffered of a Alzheimer disease, in the begining of the sickness to keep your ability to memorize some things but you loose progressively your mind. Which moment does god will choose ? I mean, Which state of your brain will be choosen to be restored ?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  If you have not already done so, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.

Comment: Man's physical body is animated by the soul. The God given soul were given free-will, intellect and memory. When it separates the body return to  dust. I think the brain has no memory after death and we might not need it in eternal life,we will be like angels.. With  faculties of intelllect and memories in supernatural form. Godbless

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about what happens during the "[resurrection of the dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_of_the_dead)". That term is used in both the Bible and the Apostles' Creed (which the vast majority of Christians accept) and discusses how people will be brought back to life when Christ comes again.

The Bible does not go into a great deal about human anatomy (the word "brain" never appears), so we don't have a verse specifically answering your question. The most detailed description of the resurrection of the dead is Paul's explanation in [1 Corinthians 15:35-54](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A35%E2%80%9354&version=NIV). Of note is verses 42-44 (NIV):

> So will it be with the resurrection of the dead. The body that is sown is perishable, it is raised imperishable; it is sown in dishonor, it is raised in glory; it is sown in weakness, it is raised in power; it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body.

There are two main interpretations of this and other Bible passages that deal with it:

1. We will be given completely new "spiritual bodies" (with no connection to our earthly bodies) at the resurrection of the dead. This interpretation assumes "[dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism)": the belief that that our spirit/soul is completely independent of our earthly body and will survive intact no matter how damaged our bodies become.
2. Our earthly bodies will be put back together and become improved "spiritual bodies". This may or may not include a belief in dualism.

In both cases, it doesn't matter whether or not your brain and the rest of your body was destroyed in a car accident. Either you will be given a replacement body or your original body will be reformed. If you were impaired due to an ailment such as Alzheimer's disease, then your improved body would presumably not have that and you would be unhindered.

(Wikipedia has an excellent [summary of differing views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_of_the_dead#Views_in_Christianity) between different denominations and theologians over time, including several points about the resurrection of the dead that are beyond the scope of this question such as whether we immediately gain spiritual bodies in heaven or whether that will happen to everyone at once in the future).